# Slick slider using horizontal scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I have a slick slider that I can slide by dragging, or using arrows or dots. I want to be able to scroll the slides using a horizontal scrollbar.

With this snippet when the mousewheel moves a `scroll` class is added to the `draggable` element to show the scrollbar and after 3 seconds this class is removed. I want it to be still visible if I scroll with that scroll bar.

```js
var slider = $('#slider');

slider.slick({
  dots: false,
  arrows: false,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  infinite: false
});

slider.on('wheel', (function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  if (e.originalEvent.deltaY < 0) {
    $(this).slick('slickNext');
  } else {
    $(this).slick('slickPrev');
  }

  slider.children('.slick-list').addClass('scroll');
  timer = setTimeout(function() {
    slider.children('.slick-list').removeClass('scroll')
  }, 3000);
}));
```

```css
#slider {
  width: 420px;
  margin: auto;
  background: #000;
  padding: 10px;
}

.slide {
  max-width: 220px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.scroll {
  overflow-x: scroll !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.css" />
<div id="slider">
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/200">
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/200">
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/200">
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried to detect `scroll` event but it's not working:

```
slider.on('scroll', function() {
  slider.children('.slick-list').addClass('scroll');
  timer = setTimeout(function() {
    slider.children('.slick-list').removeClass('scroll');
  }, 3000); 
});
```

How to detect dragging the horizontal scrollbar to keep the `scroll` class added?